# Is there any way to reposition/shift the node text in tikz, without creating extra nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I don't like the default positioning of the labels Q1 and Q2 below; is there a way to move or shift them relative to the circuit symbols? I know I could do `\node[nigbt,label={something}]` but it seems wrong.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american, font=\sffamily]  
\node[nigbt](q1) at (0,0) {Q1};
\node[nigbt](q2) at (0,2) {Q2};

\draw 
(1,-0.8) node[]{dummy}         % not sure why this is necessary
(q2.E) to (q1.C) 
(q1.E) |- (-2,-1) to [C](-2,3) -| (q2.C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For some reason, I need that line with the dummy node, otherwise Q1 and Q2's labels don't show up at all. (???)

---

I can create extra nodes, and get exactly what I want, but it seems unnecessary:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american, font=\sffamily]  
\node[nigbt](q1) at (0,0) {};
\node[nigbt](q2) at (0,2) {};
\node[above] at (q1.B){Q1};
\node[above] at (q2.B){Q2};

\draw 
(1,-0.8) node[]{dummy}
(q2.E) to (q1.C) 
(q1.E) |- (-2,-1) to [C](-2,3) -| (q2.C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without the dummy node your labels are still drawn, but are outside the area shown by `standalone`. Try `\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}`.

Comment: `xshift` and `yshift` can be used to nudge nodes hither and thither.

Comment: Though I can't see why `label` would be 'wrong' here. It seems the appropriate solution, really.

Comment: @JasonS Done, but I omitted the `[american, font=\sffamily]` after `tikzpicture`. For some reason that was giving me a circle between Q1 and Q2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the dummy node your labels are still drawn, but are outside the area shown by `standalone`. They can be revealed by adding a border.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[nigbt](q1) at (0,0) {Q1};
\node[nigbt](q2) at (0,2) {Q2};

\draw 
(q2.E) to (q1.C) 
(q1.E) |- (-2,-1) to [C](-2,3) -| (q2.C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]